# Problems with Visual studio code DPI or rendering settings

Tags: visual-studio-code, rendering, dpi

[my screen showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0fxF.png)

Hi,

I am currently having issues with VSC and rendering of the program.
After a few seconds the program starts acting weird, as if an infections is spreading throughout the screen. I have tried all kinds of solutions and cant seem to fix it. I want to know if anyone else ever faced a problem like this?? I did try to detatch my external monitor and just use my laptop, but that does not seem to fix the problem. Any takers on this??

Comment: disable graphics acceleration

Comment: How and where? In VS code? I already added this " "disable-hardware-acceleration": true, " to argv.json file

Comment: have you uncommented the line and restarted VSC

Comment: I found a solution on reddit: Nvidia control panel

Manage 3d settings

Global

Image sharpening

Disable

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/fl8hnu/white_web_glitch_vs_code_help/